# Crossed module classification theorem and $H^3(G; A)$

Tags: cohomology

We are interested in "Crossed Module Classification Theorem (Two crossed modules with kernel $A$ and cokernel $G$ determined the same class in $H^3(G;A)$ if and only if they are equivalent.)".

We study the works of Charles A. Weibel "An Introduction To Homological Algebra", Saunders Mac Lane "Historical Note, Cohomolgy Groups $H^n(G;M)$" and Joseph J. Rotman "An Introduction to Homological Algebra". Weibel says:

> Consider a $4$-term exact sequence with $A$ central in $N$; $0\to A\to N\to E\to G\to 1$ and choose a based section $\sigma : G \to E$ of $\pi$; as in the theory of factor sets, the map $[] : G\times G \to \ker\pi$ defined by $[g,h] = \sigma(g)\sigma(h)\sigma(gh)^{-1}$ satisfies a nonabelian cocycle condition $[f,g][fg,h] = \sigma(f)[g,h]\sigma(f)^{-1}[f,gh]$. We can lift each $[f,g]$ to an element $[[f,g]]$ of $N$.
>
> Given a crossed module $N\to E$ we set $A = \ker\alpha$ and $G = \operatorname{coker}\alpha$; $G$ is a group because $\alpha(N)$ is normal in $E$, $A$ is in the center of $N$ and $G$ acts on $A$, so that $A$ is a $G$ module and we have the sequence $0\to A\to N\to E\to G\to 1$. Assuming that $N\to E$ is a crossed module, the failure of $[[f,g]]$ to satisfy the cocycle condition is given by the function $c : G\times G\times G \to A$ defined by $c(f,g,h)[[f,g]][[fg,h]] = \sigma(f)[[g,h]]\sigma(f)^{-1}[[f,gh]]$.

How can we check that $c$ is a $3$-cocycle, whose class in $H^3(G;A)$ is independent of choices of $\sigma$ and $[[f,g]]$? Can we define the function of $c$ explicitly?

Comment: Please ask questions in a readable form.

Answer (score 2):

The book partially titled [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html) (NAT) (pdf available) has an extensive treatment of crossed modules and their role in cohomology and in homotopy classification.

A main difference from  standard homological algebra texts is the use of crossed complexes and of free crossed resolutions of groups. In particular, some seemingly complicated cocycle conditions turn out to be related to a boundary rule in a standard free crossed complex; so the rule you give does, with the appropriate conventions, become $c\delta =0$.

Background is given in the exposition `Groupoids and crossed objects in algebraic topology',Homology, homotopy and applications, 1 (1999) 1-78, available [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/GRENoble09.pdf). This contains some calculations of the $k$-invariants  of some crossed modules.

Further calculations are available in the paper

G. Ellis and Le Van Luyen, "Homotopy 2-types of low order", available from the preprint list of [Graham Ellis](http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/).